# Experience Builder Customer Portal Insufficient Privileges on Self Registration

Tags: lightning-experience, customer-portal, self-registration, user-registration, registration

**Some quick info:**

- Salesforce Edition: Non-Profit
- Where: Experience builder
- What: Registration error, insufficient privileges
- My profile: Full sys admin

**Full details:**

I am using the Customer Portal template in Salesforce Experience Builder. I've gone through the official Salesforce customer portal implementation guide and followed various forum post guides.

When I go to register a new user in the experience site -- it is published -- and I fill in a name, email, and password, I get an error message (displayed in the section below).

Immediately below you can see the options (nil) to choose a profile on the "Login & Registration" section of the Administration tab for Experience Builder.

[image: Screenshot of Profile Selection]

I believe fixing this could solve my issue but I cannot find where to get profiles enabled there. I thought it was in the "Members" section of the Administration tab for Experience Builder however I have two profiles under "Selected Profiles" (image below) and neither of them show up (image above).

[image: Selected profiles displaying sysadmin and defNewUser]

The default new user profile is a custom profile I set up in Salesforce. I've enabled "lightning login" in the general user permissions section of the profiles settings for the profile. I have also added the site to the "default experience cloud site" section of the profile settings.

List of things I have tried is available in point form at the bottom.

There is likely something I have missed but I can't find it in any documentation or posts online. Thanks in advance.

**Full error message:**

```
Insufficient Privileges: You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.
```

**Things I have tried:**

- Allow using standard external profiles for self-registration and user creation
- Enabled lightning login for the profile I want to assign to new users
- Added the site to the default experience cloud site in profile settings
- Enabled "lightning login user" and "lightning experience user" in custom permission set which has been "selected" in the "Members" section of the Administration tab for experience builder
- Probably tried some other stuff but I'm currently blanking on everything I have tried as I have been having this issue for some time now.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Thanks for the detail you've included in your question, that's really helpful. A couple of things I'd just like to clarify on the new profile you've created, is it associated to a license type? And was it cloned from one of the standard Salesforce profiles?

Comment: @CallumMacErlich I believe I cloned a profile. The user license is "Identity". Also, it may be useful to know that I am developing in a sandbox environment.

Comment: That sounds like the problem then. "Identity" is an internal identity only license, whereas you need to have cloned the 'External Identity User' standard profile with the 'External Identity' license type.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich What if there isn't an External Identity User profile?

Comment: The only 'external' profile is a Chatter External User which I don't think will work for my needs

Comment: No external identity available on "Your Account > Products" page either

Comment: Do you have any Community licenses available in your org?

Comment: There are customer community profiles available for purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this page show up when an Identity or External Identity license was not assigned to the Connected App and they tried to use the SAML app link. I doubt that is what is happening here, but the page is pretty generic. The page does show in the "classic" site.com method and not the Lightning ExperienceBuilder page.